# flutter, is it mandatory to add a license?

Tags: flutter

I made an application in Flutter and I will publish it on the play store. Do I have to add the licenses of the packages (all of them) such as the provider I use?

license example =

```
MIT License

Copyright (c) 2016, Alexandre Roux Tekartik.

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
SOFTWARE.
```

How can I add it even if it is not mandatory? For example, I need to create a special page for it within the application or is it sufficient if I add it inside the application codes?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a predefined widget for this, if you don't want to program it yourself: AboutDialog

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AboutDialog-class.html